# value cannot be null in wcf using xml

Tags: c#, string, wcf, xmlreader, stringreader

i'm triyng converto string to xml but when code is running "value cannot be null" how cani fix that ? project run in windows phone 8

```
public string baslıkbul(baslıkı ba)
    {
        SqlConnection bag = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["baglantı"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        bag.Open();
        SqlCommand yap = new SqlCommand("select Baslık from AN where AD=@ad",bag);
        yap.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad", ba.AD);
        yap.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(yap);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        string s = ds.GetXml(); /// this line is running

        XmlReader okuyucu = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(s));
        while(okuyucu.Read())
        {
            if(okuyucu.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                switch(okuyucu.Name)
                {
                    case"Baslık":
                        s = Convert.ToString(okuyucu.ReadString());

                        s = ba.Baslık;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }


        bag.Close();
        return ba.Baslık;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the value you supply to your `ad` parameter (ie. `ba.AD`) is `null`. In case that is the value you want to use in your WHERE clause for filtering, then you should pass [System.DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: thanks for answer but ba.AD is not null  i can get xml file as xml in windows phone but i want to do this <NewDataSet> abc    <NewDataSet>   abc is not coming when i'm try value is be NULL